# Stop logger to print from new line

Tags: java, logging, printing

I'm new to java, trying to use logger instead of System.out.print();

Making cows and bulls game and can't figure out how to make logger printing each digit from new line and instead print it as one number.

Example :

```
logger.info(player + ", you lose. The number is : ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
                        logger.info("{}", random[i]);
                    }
                }
```

output is :

```
17:54:27.668 [main] INFO com.bullsandcow.GameScreen - Viktors, you lose. The number is : 
17:54:27.668 [main] INFO com.bullsandcow.GameScreen - 3
17:54:27.673 [main] INFO com.bullsandcow.GameScreen - 6
17:54:27.673 [main] INFO com.bullsandcow.GameScreen - 4
17:54:27.673 [main] INFO com.bullsandcow.GameScreen - 7
```

What I want is to print 3647 as one number.

Comment: build the string and log at last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure what you want, but if you just need the random number in the same line, you can try:

```
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
    s += random[i];
}
logger.info("{}", s);
```

Comment: please don't append strings like this in a loop, use the StringBuilder solution. New objects will be created and will have to be garbage collected over and over again. Even if for this small example it might not be relevant, get used to StringBuilders for string concatenation in loops. (It doesn't matter for a single line though, but just for using in loops.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `random` is int[], what you need is to combine all element into a String.

```
        ...
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i: random){
            builder.append(i);
        }
        logger.info("{}", builder.toString());
```

Comment: Please, wrap that creation of the string inside a `if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {}` to prevent the string operations.